# Progress-bar of "earned new privilege" shows incorrect percentage

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, privileges

When a new privilege is earned, one can see the following card on their profile page:

[image: 'See votes' privilege]

Now, if I understand correctly, the progress bar's value indicates either the progress of the newly earned tag (which should be 100%) or <sup>(unlikely)</sup> the overall progress of all tags. If it's the former, the displayed value is (obviously) far less than 100%. And if it's the latter, I checked on a different site with a different privilege and the displayed value was identical:

[image: 'See reduced ads' privilege]

Also, checking the HTML element shows that it should be at 100%:

[image: Expected value]

But the CSS `width` property is set to `0%` (thanks to [John Omielan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/562482/john-omielan)'s answer below) and that seems to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Luuklag I think it's a bit related but seems like a different issue.

Comment: hmmm I have seen that so many times, never noticed it. Nice catch.

Comment: Even with [Mod Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRwtO.jpg) you're still at ***0***, but in that case 2/5ths of the way would be more appropriate because [5000 is the *maximum*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and Mod Tools are earned at 2K on that site. It should either be based on: the *maximum* (privilege level), the categorical level (EG: category of Editor) (not that all privilege levels have a higher categorical privilege), or it should be 100% (and less as you progress towards the last level) - either counting from the last level or zero. **Needs Bounty**.

Answer (score 2):

I see in the next line after the red circle that `style="width: 0%"`. I believe this may be the cause of the problem. For example, according to [CSS width property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_width.asp), the "%" option "Defines the width in percent of the containing block". Also, with [Tryit Editor v3.6](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_width_percent), changing any of the width values to 0% and then pressing the green "Run" button causes those images to disappear on my Microsoft Edge browser, e.g.,

[image: Image with the width set to 0% for the second and third images]

As such, unless there's some reason such as this doesn't do what I expect or there's a style override making it a moot setting, changing the width there to 100% might solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed, increasing the width value makes the progress bar advances. I don't know how I didn't notice that. Also, the progress bar of the _next_ privilege uses the same value for `aria-valuenow` and `width`. So, this does really seem like a bug.